# Haskell how to read a file specified as a command line argument

Tags: haskell, stdin, readfile

I need to write a haskell program that retrieves a file from command line argument and read that file line by line. I was wondering how to approach this, do I have to get the command line argument as a string and parse that into openFile or something? I'm quite new to haskell so I'm pretty lost, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, if one wants to specific a file as an argument then one will have to get the arguments and send that to openFile.

[`System.Environment.getArgs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-Environment.html#v%3agetArgs) returns the arguments as a list. So given `test_getArgs.hs` like

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)

main = do
        args <- getArgs
        print args
```

Then,

```
$ ghc test_getArgs.hs -o test_getArgs
$ ./test_getArgs
[]
$ ./test_getArgs arg1 arg2 "arg with space"
["arg1","arg2","arg with space"]
```

So, if you want to read a single file:

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.IO (openFile, ReadMode, hGetContents)

main = do
        args <- getArgs
        file <- openFile (head args) ReadMode
        text <- hGetContents file
        -- do stuff with `text`
```

(N.B. that code has no error recovery: what to do if there were no arguments and so `args` was empty (`head` will fail)? What if the file doesn't exist/isn't readable?)

Comment: what would be a good way to sum the numbers of the IO string?

Comment: @SNpn, Sum which numbers? (you'll have to give more information)

Comment: sorry, the file contains a list of integers (set one integer per line) I need to retrieve the file and sum the integers, I've tried to `print . sum (text)`

Comment: You might find [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:map), [`read`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:read) and [`lines`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:lines) useful (those are all links to the documentation). (Also, that code should be `print . sum $ text`, since `.` composes only functions, and what you've written is parsed as `print . (sum text)` )

Comment: You could avoid the `head` call altogether if you used pattern matching: `(firstArg:_) <- getArgs`. Also, consider using [`withFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.2.0.0/doc/html/System-IO.html#v%3AwithFile) to make sure that the file gets closed.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe, I believe using pattern matching makes checking for errors (i.e. missing filename) tricky. Good point about `withFile`.

Comment: @dbaupp: I believe it's actually impossible to handle unsuccessful pattern matches in the IO monad: when pattern matching in a `do` block is unsuccessful, the `fail` function of the monad will be called - in the case of the IO monad, that calls `error`, which makes the program terminate. However, since you have to check for an empty list anyway, you could just use [`when`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:when) to handle empty lists before doing the pattern match.

Answer (score 3):

First, use [`getArgs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.2.0.0/doc/html/System-Environment.html#v%3AgetArgs) to get the command line arguments. I guess the first one is most interesting to you. Then, use the [`openFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/3.0.3.2/doc/html/System-IO.html#v%3AopenFile) function to open the file. Finally, use [`hGetLine`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/GHC-IO-Handle.html#v%3ahGetLine) to read from the opened file line-by-line.